# how to update axshockwaveflashobjects

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, apache-flex

i am using this in my project , i think the project was created long ago , but am in need of an updated version , when i right click the form it shows flah player 10 point soemthing . i think the shockwave version now is 12 , how to add it , i have tried finding the .ocx file but i couldnt find it , any ideas?

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axShockwaveFlash1 = new AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash();
    axShockwaveFlash1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panel1.Controls.Add(axShockwaveFlash1);
    axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = @"something here";
    axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to install the [this](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/21/flashplayer_21_ax_debug.exe).

You should then have the latest version of the OCX file in C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash and C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash, and your references to Shockwave Flash Object should be automatically updated to point to these updated paths.

Shockwave Flash not in COM list AND no OCX to register manually[^]